# mysql connect to remote database specified by ip and server name

Tags: mysql, ruby, host

Trying to connect to a database using the mysql2 gem through a VPN.

I'm connected to the VPN, and can access secure pages via browser. I have the following info:

```
server: ###-*********
ip: ###.###.##.###
port: ####
username: ********
password: ********
schema: ***********_***
```

And the gem wants:

```
username (check)
password (check)
host     (?)
port     (check)
database (?)
```

I've tried putting the ip as the host and using schema and server for database, but it won't connect.

Comment: How are you trying to connect?  Can you ssh into the host?  Are you using the default port for mysql of 3306?  You don't know the name of the database?

Comment: Try to connect by telnet first: `telnet <ip address> <port>`.

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev it said connection refused. I feel like it may be something to do with there being a server and an ip. Is there any way to combine them, or specify the server to access with telnet?